# How can I download a data file (.mp3,.wav) using wxWebRequest?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a link and I'm sending it to `wxWebRequest` to download a file, but it doesn't seem to return anything. The only "download functionality" I've got working so far is downloading webpages with the `AsString()` function in the `WxWebRequest` class, and also Images by passing `*(evt.GetResponse().GetStream())` to the `wxImage` constructor. `wxSound` only accepts wav files, so passing a stream to `wxSound` won't work with the need to download mp3s.

Here's my code so far:

```cpp
string modifyVocabFrame::downloadBinaryFileFromURL_ReturnFilename(string urltempstr)
{
    string urlstr = to_lower_copy(urltempstr);
    
     wxWebRequest request = wxWebSession::GetDefault().CreateRequest(
        this,
        urltempstr//"   https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/logos/blocks.png"
    );
 
if ( !request.IsOk() ) 
{
    cout<<"Request is not OK. Aborting URL:"<<urltempstr<<endl;
    string strexit="fail_RequestNotOK";
    return strexit;// This is not expected, but handle the error somehow.
}
 
// Bind state event
Bind(wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_STATE, [](wxWebRequestEvent& evt) {
    switch (evt.GetState())
    {
        // Request completed
        case wxWebRequest::State_Completed:
        {
            string urlstr = MainFrame::convertWxStringToStdString(evt.GetResponse().GetSuggestedFileName());
            if(
                MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".jpeg") ||
                MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".png") ||
                MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".gif")
                //containsStr(urlstr,".jpeg") ||
              )
                {
                    wxImage image(*(evt.GetResponse().GetStream()));
                    if (image.IsOk())
                    {
                        wxLogInfo("Image successfully downloaded");
                        std::vector<std::string> results;

                        split(results, urlstr, is_any_of("/"));

                        //get last segment of the URL to retrieve the filename
                        string basefilename = results[results.size()-1];
                     
                        wxString DlFilePath = wxString("/Downloads/"+basefilename);
                        
                        if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".jpeg") ||
                            MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".jpg"))
                                image.SaveFile(wxString(DlFilePath),wxBITMAP_TYPE_JPEG);
                        else if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".gif"))
                            image.SaveFile(wxString(DlFilePath),wxBITMAP_TYPE_GIF);
                        else if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".png"))
                            image.SaveFile(wxString(DlFilePath),wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
                            
                        return MainFrame::convertWxStringToStdString(DlFilePath);
                        //sdfgsdf;;///
                    }
                    else
                        cout<<"LogoImage download failed. URL="<<urlstr<<endl;
                    
                    break;
                }
                else if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".mp3") ||
                        MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".wav") )
                {
                    //wxSound tempSound(*evt.GetResponse().Get);
                    //if (logoImage.IsOk())
                    //  wxLogInfo("Image successfully downloaded");
         
                    wxWebResponse webres = evt.GetResponse();
                    if(webres.IsOk())
                    {
                        
                        wxString wxsndfname = webres.GetDataFile();
                        
                        std::vector<std::string> results;

                        split(results, urlstr, is_any_of("/"));

                        //get last segment of the URL to retrieve the filename
                        string basefilename = results[results.size()-1];
                     
                        wxString DlFilePath = wxString("/Downloads/"+basefilename);
                        
                        if(wxCopyFile(wxsndfname, DlFilePath, true))
                        {
                            //succesfully downloaded file to DLFilePath
                            //update sndfilename tbox
                            return MainFrame::convertWxStringToStdString(DlFilePath);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<"Failed to copy sound file over! From:"<<wxsndfname<<" to:"<<DlFilePath<<endl;
                            return MainFrame::convertWxStringToStdString(wxsndfname);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"Sound file download failed. URL="<<urlstr<<endl;
                    }
         
                    break;
                }
        }
        // Request failed
        case wxWebRequest::State_Failed:
            wxLogError("Could not load logo: %s", evt.GetErrorDescription());
            break;
    }
    string strexit="fail2_reachedEndOfDownloadBinaryFileFunc";
    return strexit;
});
```

The problem is that `webres.GetDataFile()` seems to return an empty string for the file name. The image download functionality using a `dataStream *` seems to fine for downloading images, but `webres.GetDataFile();` doesn't seem to work as expected so the wav,.mp3 download functionality doesn't work.

I've tried using the wxHTTP solution on here, but it doesn't handle HTTPS like `wxWebRequest` does, and it also didn't compile properly in wxWidgets 3.2 complaining of an incomplete data type for the `inputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Had to set the filestorage mode prior to sending off the request, and then had to use wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_STATE for the event type, and then use getDataFile() to get the tempfile, and then finally renaming the file to another directory to actually use the file. here's the essential parts of my code in regards to this.

...

```
void modifyVocabFrame::downloadBinaryFileFromURL_ReturnFilename(string urltempstr)
{
    cout<<"EnterFunc downloadBinaryFileFromURL_ReturnFilename"<<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            
    string urlstr = to_lower_copy(urltempstr);

    cout<<"Requesting url:"<<urltempstr<<endl;
     wxWebRequest request = wxWebSession::GetDefault().CreateRequest(
        this,
        urltempstr//"   https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/logos/blocks.png"
    );
 
if ( !request.IsOk() ) 
{
    cout<<"Request is not OK. Aborting URL:"<<urltempstr<<endl;
    string strexit="fail_RequestNotOK";
    //doneFileDL = true;
    return;// This is not expected, but handle the error somehow.
}

    cout<<"Request IsOK!"<<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    
 
    if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".mp3") ||
        MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".wav"))
        {
            cout<<"SettingStorage to File"<<endl;
            request.SetStorage(wxWebRequest::Storage_File);
        }
    cout<<"Binding wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_DATA, &modifyVocabFrame::OnRequest"<<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
 
// Bind state event
unbindHandler(2); //onRequest bind
//thisFr->Bind(wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_DATA, &modifyVocabFrame::OnRequest, this);

cout<<"Sending request now"<<endl;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
 
// Start the request
request.Start();
}

void modifyVocabFrame::unbindHandler(int i)
{
    cout<<"Entering UnbindHandler"<<endl;
    if(i==0)
    {
        thisFr->Unbind(wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_STATE, &modifyVocabFrame::OnPageRequest, this);
        cout<<"Unbound OnPageRequest"<<endl;
    }
    if(i==1)
    {
        thisFr->Unbind(wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_STATE, &modifyVocabFrame::OnRequest, this);
        cout<<"Unbound OnRequest"<<endl;
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        thisFr->Bind(wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_STATE, &modifyVocabFrame::OnRequest, this);
        cout<<"Bound OnRequest";
    }
    if(i==3)
    {
        thisFr->Bind(wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_STATE, &modifyVocabFrame::OnPageRequest, this);
        cout<<"Bound OnPageRequest"<<endl;
    }
}

void modifyVocabFrame::OnRequest(wxWebRequestEvent& evt)
{
    cout<<"Entering WEBREQUEST PROCESSING"<<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    
    string urlstrlower = to_lower_copy(urlstr);
    
    string fnamestr;
    
    if(evt.GetState()==wxWebRequest::State_Active)
    {
        cout<<"STATE ACTIVE. RETURNING."<<endl;
        return;
    }
    
    switch (evt.GetState())
    {
        // Request completed
        case wxWebRequest::State_Completed:
        {
            fnamestr = MainFrame::convertWxStringToStdString(evt.GetResponse().GetSuggestedFileName());
            cout<<"urlstr from evt.GetResponse().GetSuggestedFileName():"<<urlstr<<endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

            if(
                MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".jpeg") ||
                MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".png") ||
                MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".gif")
                //containsStr(urlstr,".jpeg") ||
              )
                {
                    wxImage image(*(evt.GetResponse().GetStream()));
                    if (image.IsOk())
                    {
                        wxLogInfo("Image successfully downloaded");
                        std::vector<std::string> results;

                        split(results, urlstr, is_any_of("/"));

                        //get last segment of the URL to retrieve the filename
                        string basefilename = results[results.size()-1];
                     
                        wxString DlFilePath = wxString("Downloads/Images/"+basefilename);
                        
                        if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".jpeg") ||
                            MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".jpg"))
                                image.SaveFile(wxString(DlFilePath),wxBITMAP_TYPE_JPEG);
                        else if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".gif"))
                            image.SaveFile(wxString(DlFilePath),wxBITMAP_TYPE_GIF);
                        else if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstr,".png"))
                            image.SaveFile(wxString(DlFilePath),wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
                            
                        //doneFileDL = true;
                        //string downfname = ;
                        DLedFname = DlFilePath;
                        //string exitstr = "Finished with image";
                        //return;
                        //return MainFrame::convertWxStringToStdString(DlFilePath);
                        //sdfgsdf;;///
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"LogoImage download failed. URL="<<urlstr<<endl;
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".mp3") ||
                        MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".wav") )
                {
                    //wxSound tempSound(*evt.GetResponse().Get);
                    //if (logoImage.IsOk())
                    //  wxLogInfo("Image successfully downloaded");
         
                    wxWebResponse webres = evt.GetResponse();
                    if(webres.IsOk())
                    {
                        
                        wxString wxsndfname = webres.GetDataFile();
                        
                        std::vector<std::string> results;

                        split(results, urlstrlower, is_any_of("/"));

                        //get last segment of the URL to retrieve the filename
                        string basefilename = results[results.size()-1];
                     
                        wxString DlFilePath = wxString("Downloads/Audio/"+basefilename);
                        
                        //if(wxCopyFile(wxsndfname, DlFilePath, true))
                        if (wxRenameFile(wxsndfname, DlFilePath) )
                        {
                            //succesfully downloaded file to DLFilePath
                            //update sndfilename tbox
                            cout<<"Succesful file copy!"<<endl;
                            //doneFileDL = true;


                            DLedFname = MainFrame::convertWxStringToStdString(DlFilePath);
                            //string exitstr = "SUCCESS";
                            //return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<"Failed to copy sound file over! From:"<<wxsndfname<<" to:"<<DlFilePath<<endl;
                            
                            //doneFileDL = true;

                            DLedFname = MainFrame::convertWxStringToStdString(wxsndfname);
                            //string exitstr = "SUCCESS";
                            //return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"Sound file download failed. URL="<<urlstr<<endl;
                        return;
                    }
         
                    break;
                }
        }
        // Request failed
        case wxWebRequest::State_Failed:
            cout<<"case wxWebRequest::State_Failed:"<<endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            wxLogError("Could not load logo: %s", evt.GetErrorDescription());
            return;
            //break;
    }
    
    cout<<"Reached end of WEBREQUEST PROCESSING"<<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    //doneFileDL = true;
    //string strexit="fail2_reachedEndOfDownloadBinaryFileFunc";
    
    //cout<<"Done with DownloadBinaryFileFromURL func: "<<endl;
    //  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        
        
        string downfname = DLedFname;
                    
        cout<<"fileDownload COMPLETE: "<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        //Now update any of the two textboxes
        
        if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".jpeg") ||
            MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".jpg") ||
            MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".png") ||
            MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".gif"))
            {
                cout<<"Setting the picFileTbox"<<endl;
                wxTextCtrl* picFileTbox = GetTextCtrl125_pictureFilePath();
                picFileTbox->SetValue(wxString::FromUTF8(downfname));
            }
            else if(MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".mp3") ||
                    MainFrame::containsStr(urlstrlower,".wav"))
            {
                cout<<"Setting the audFileTbox"<<endl;
                wxTextCtrl* audFileTbox = GetTextCtrl123_audFilePath();
                audFileTbox->SetValue(wxString::FromUTF8(downfname));
            }
            else
            {
                    cout<<"DIDN'T SET TBOX:"<<endl;
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
            }
    
        cout<<"Reached End of Binary File DL "<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        CallAfter(&modifyVocabFrame::unbindHandler,1);
}
```

...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).